# Receiving multiples files from server

Tags: android, file, file-handling, readfile, writefile

```
 private fun receiveVideoFromServer() {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            var socket: Socket? = null
            try {
                // Replace placeholders with server details
                val host = "192.168.0.34" // YOUR ACTUAL SERVER IP
                val port = 12345       // YOUR ACTUAL SERVER PORT
                // Choose a suitable save directory and file path
                val directory = requireNotNull(externalCacheDir) {
                    Log.e("VideoReceiveError", "External cache directory is null")
                    return@launch // Gracefully handle the error
                }

                // Connect to server
                socket = Socket()
                socket.connect(InetSocketAddress(host, port), 200000)
                var filecount = 0
                while(filecount<12) {

                    val saveFilePath = File(directory, "video$filecount.mp4") // Change if needed
                    // Input stream for reading video data
                    val inputStream = socket.getInputStream()
                    //   val inputStream = BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream())
                    // Create output stream for saving the video
                    val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(saveFilePath)
                    // Receive and write video data in chunks
                    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                    var bytesRead: Int
                    while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    }
                    // Finish writing and close streams
                    fileOutputStream.close()
                    // Success message and optional video playback (use a suitable video player library)
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this@MainActivity,
                            "Video received successfully: $saveFilePath",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                        Log.d("ReciveSucc", "Video received successfully: $saveFilePath")
                        // ... Play video
                    }
                    filecount++
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // Handle network errors, connection failures, and other exceptions
                Log.e("VideoReceiveError", "Error receiving video: ${e.message}", e)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Error receiving video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
            } finally {
                // Close socket gracefully
                try {
                    socket?.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.e("SocketCloseError", "Error closing socket: ${e.message}", e)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In this given code i am not abele to receive multiples files from the server,Problem is when first file is recive succesfully and after other files are coming 0Bytes and continues coming,and server send only 12 files.Server is Raspberry pi and my phone work as client and server send all files.

I am try to receve all file completly.

Comment: No. This code consumes all 12 files at once and writes all to the first file. Please check file sizes.